# packing objects as json with django?

Tags: django, python-2.7

I've run into a snag in my views.
Here "filtered_posts" is array of Django objects coming back from the model. 
I am having a little trouble figuring out how to get as text data that I can
later pack into json instead of using serializers.serialize...
What results is that the data comes double-escaped (escaped once by serializers.serialize and a second time by json.dumps).
I can't figure out how to return the data from the db in the same way that it would come back if I were using the MySQLdb lib directly, in other words, as strings, instead of references to objects. As it stands if I take out the serializers.serialize, I get a list of these django objects, and it doesn't even list them all (abbreviates them with '...(remaining elements truncated)...'. 
I don't think I should, but should I be using the __unicode__() method for this? (and if so, how should I be evoking it?)

```
JSONtoReturn = json.dumps({                                                                                                                                       
    'lowest_id': user_posts[limit - 1].id,                                                                                                                        
    'user_posts': serializers.serialize("json", list(filtered_posts)),
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The Django Rest Framework looks pretty neat. I've used Tastypie before, too.

I've also done RESTful APIs that don't include a framework. When I do that, I define `toJSON` methods on my objects, that return dictionaries, and cascade the call to related elements. Then I call `json.dumps()` on that. It's a lot of work, which is why the frameworks are worth looking at.

Comment: what's the best way to return the object as a dictionary?

Comment: "Best" will depend a little on your problem domain. My point of view is, identify which attributes from your object will be needed in the Javascript part of the application. Copy those into a dictionary, return that. Alternately, you can use a dictionary comprehension to return "everything": `{k:v for (k,v) in self.__dict__.items() if type(v) in (int, float, str, unicode, dict) and (not k.startswith('_'))}` but that might lead to information leaks.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is [Django Rest Framework](http://django-rest-framework.org/). It handles related objects in exactly thew way you're expecting it to (you can include a nested object, like in your example, or simply have it output the PK of the related object for the key).